# C# unknown index out of range exception?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I was learning about the switch...case statement and i cant find out whats wrong with the following code. Once i debug i goes back to visual studio and gives me a error. An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in C sharp.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace C_sharp
{
class Program
{
    //this will demonstrate the switch statement
    static void Main(string[] userInput)
    {
        int input = int.Parse(userInput[0]);

        switch(input)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("you typed 1 (one) as the first command line argument");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("you typed 2 (two) as the first command line argument");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("you 3 (three) as the first command line argument");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Like the error says - you are trying to access an array index that it beyond the length of the array.

Comment: I think you confuse arguments to pass to the exe and the user inputs

Comment: @Ant P im not sure what that means, how do i fix this?

Comment: The stack trace should tell you what line is throwing the exception.  When you look at that line, you'll probably see that it involves an array.  When you look at the array, you'll probably find that it doesn't have as many items in it as you think it does.

Comment: Run your program like `prog input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio should be highlighting a particular line when it hits that exception.  Let me guess: this one?

```
int input = int.Parse(userInput[0]);
```

That's nothing to do with the `switch` statement, but to do with the arguments to `Main()`.  Those get there from the command line, for example when you invoke your program by typing

```
command some-parameter
```

at the C:\ command prompt, or from your Command line arguments which you can set in the Debug page when you look at the Properties of your project.

Answer (score 3):

`userInput[0]`, you're assuming that array has at least one item in it and the reference isn't null. Neither of those things are guaranteed. Some error checking would be good, you could also just pass a command line argument to the program when you invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

You must call that program with commandline arguments. Otherwise, userInput does not contain any element. Then, userInput[0] will trigger this error.

BTW, it helps to look at the stacktrace of the exception in order to find the culprit more easily. It would have pointed you to the corresponding line.

Comment: To achieve this (passing command line arguments) in visual studio: On the project properties dialog in the Debug tab there should be a Command line arguments field. Enter a value there.